# Implicit conversion from std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> to std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>

Tags: c++

I have a function requiring `const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>&` as signature. It seems that compiler doesn't allow me to pass in a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`. Wondering why it cannot implicitly convert from `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>`.

I tried passing an object of `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` to a function requiring `const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>&` as signature. It fails to compile.

Comment: Since there is no implicit conversion between std::vectors with different template arguments. Just write helper function: https://godbolt.org/z/aqo1oT3od

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there is no implicit conversion between `std::vector`s with different template arguments. Just write helper function:

–
Marek R

```
class Foo {};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>> convert(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>& v)
{
    return {v.begin(), v.end()};
}
```

Comment: Note: that would make a copy, which might lead to a different outcome.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` are entirely different types. They look similar to the eye, but in general they may not be related at all. Consider this, for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {};

template <typename T>
requires (std::is_const_v<T>)
struct Test<T> {
  double member;
};

template <typename T>
requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
struct Test<T> {
  char ch;
};
```

Here, `Test<int>` and `Test<int const>` are completely different classes. One having a `float` member called "member" and the other a `char` member called "ch". Converting between these does not even make logical sense. Forcing a conversion would result in heavy UB.

Therefore, C++ says *in general*, that you **cannot** pretend one of these is the other and return a reference to it.